# Exporting and running Unity3D project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to get logs from Unity Application when its running on Android phone. For this I have to export Android project from Unity3D and run it using Android Studio. I am doing following steps:

1. Export Project from Unity3D by selecting **Google Android Project** options from player settings.
2. Open Android Studio and Import the autogenerated project from location drive.
3. Select **Build -> Make Project.**
4. Select **Run -> Run 'ModuleName'.**

I am getting following errors in Gradle console:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':     'ModuleName':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  at
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>     java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>     sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>     Exception in thread "main"
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 0.788 secs
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>   Exception in thread "main"

I have been working with Eclipse long ago but never faced this before. Can anyone guide me how to successfully run a Unity-Android project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Exporting and running Unity3D project to Android Studio is not really hard. Make sure the you have the latest version of **Unity(5.4)** and **Android Studio(2.1.3)**. This steps were made with the version mentioned above.

**EXPORTING TO Android Studio**:

**1**.Create a root folder that will hold the exported folders and files. Let's call it `AndroidTestProject` in this case and the full Directory will be `C:/AndroidTestProject`.

**2**.Exporting to `C:/AndroidTestProject`.

**A**.**File**->**Build Settings...**

**B**.Select **Android** on the left then tick **Google Android Project** checkbox.

*Image Description*:
[image]

**C**.Click the **Export** Button.

**D**.Select `C:/AndroidTestProject` then click the **Select Folder** Button.

*Image Description*:

[image]

Unity will build your project.

After Generating the project, a new folder will be created in the `C:/AndroidTestProject` directory. That folder will be named whatever your **Product Name** is in the **Player Settings**.  This what my product name is in the **Player Settings**:

*Image Description*:
[image]

So in my case, the new Folder name will be called **test** and will be located at `C:/AndroidTestProject/test`.

**IMPORTING INTO Android Studio**:

**1**.Create a new Folder called **AndroidStudio** in the `C:/AndroidTestProject/` directory. The full path of that folder should be `C:/AndroidTestProject/AndroidStudio`.

**A**.Open **Android Studio**. When you open Android Studio, click on **Import project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle, etc.)**

If **Import project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle, etc.)** is not displayed, close the current project by going to **File**->**Close Project**.

*Image Description*:
[image]

**B**.Go to the full directory of the exported project `C:/AndroidTestProject/test` then select the **test** folder which is the **Product Name** of your project then click **Ok**.

*Image Description*:
[image]

**C**.A new Window will pop up. Set the **Import Destination Directory** to be `C:/AndroidTestProject/AndroidStudio` which was created in step 1.

*Image Description*:
[image]

**D**.Click the **Next** Button.
Tick/Select the follwing check boxes:

- *Replace jars with dependencies, when possible*.
- *Replace library sources with dependencies, when possible*.
- *Create Gradle-style (CamelCase) module names*.

then click the **Finish** Button.

*Image Description*:
[image]

**2**.Wait for **Android Studio** to load your project.

You will get an error that looks like this:

> Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1.  Current version is
>   2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\AndroidTestProject\AndroidStudio\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip Fix
>   Gradle wrapper and re-import project
> Gradle settings

**A**.Simply click on the **Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project Gradle settings** message. If you don't see this message, make sure that you are in the **Messages** Tab. Look at the image below for more information.

*Image Description*:

[image]

**B**.Wait for **Android Studio** to finish fixing the Gradle problem.

When finished, go to **Build**->**Make Project**.

After project is done building, go to **Run**->**Run 'app'**.

**C**.A new Window will pop up. You can either chose the device to run the app on, create an emulator or chose already existing emulator to run the app. In this example we will use a real device to test.

Under **Connected Devices**, select your device then click the **OK** button.

*Image Description*:

[image]

**Extra**:

**A**.If you want to be able to debug your App, you have to enable that from **Unity**. Go back to **EXPORTING TO Android Studio** step **2B** and enable **Development Build**.Also select **Script Debugging** then click the **Export** Button.

**B**.If you want to see `Debug.Log` messages, go to the **Android Monitor** Tab in the **Android Studio**.

The circled items in the image below are important to know when Debugging in Android Studio.

*Image Description*:

[image]

This is not really hard. If you do it once, you won't need this instruction again.

Comment: Thanks! I was skipping checkboxes in part :D

Comment: I knew you were missing something. Just didn't know which part so I posted all part. Good luck with Android Studio.

Comment: What do you do if step C doesn't show up? (Import Destination Directory)
It just prompted me if I wanted to use the Gradle wrapper or configure it manually. I selected "Gradle wrapper" but it didn't give me a change to pick the destination folder, so I guess it just uses the Unity exported project folder as the Android Studio project folder?

Comment: @bigp There are multiple C's here. Which category of C? Also please bear in mind that this post is old and I plan to update it to work with Gradle.

Comment: Ah I just realized after I re-read it there was several 'C's. I was pointing out the one where it's followed by `C.A new Window will pop up. Set the Import Destination Directory to be`.

Comment: Now when I have Unity project in Android Studio I can add Java code for UI. I did that. My question is can I send data from Android to Unity and back?

Answer (score 3):

"I want to get logs from Unity Application when its running on Android phone".

You dont need to export to android project , just enable "development build" in build settings then connect your phone to your computer and enable "development mode" and "script debugging" on your phone.

then simply move to path your android sdk is installed , cd to platform-tools , run these commands from command prompt or terminal

```
adb logcat
```

if you want to just see unity logs run

```
adb logcat -s Unity
```