# Import Unity3D project to existing android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have been creating an app in Android Studio for a while and decided that I wanted to add Augmented Reality to my app. I created an AR project in Unity and exported the file as an ADT and gradle but cannot figure out how to import it into my existing project. Everything that I found was importing it into a new project. If I cannot import it into my Android Studio project then can I somehow merge both projects?

Comment: Does this help or is it not applicable? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38980792/6730803

Comment: @Fredrik that one creates a new Android studio project.  I want an already existing project

Comment: @JuanSierra did you got any procedure to integrate unity project to existing android studio project? I'm also looking for the same.

Comment: Hi have you got the answer?I am looking for same.

Comment: @sagarpotdar no I haven't. I decided to do use Kudan for AR. Came out to be pretty easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

You can import your Unity (android build) as a library into another android app. And then call the UnityPlayer Activity inside.

[Tutorial Here](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a)