# Unity hit Android DEX limit but ref count increases after removing .jars

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project that's just chock full of 3rd-party libs and has hit the DEX limit. One of the plugins is an ad mediator and there are several ad network integrations under it. So that was my first target for the removal of libraries, I just took out some of the networks. Easy.

Except that after removing .jars, the method count actually goes up instead of down. Now, my knowledge of how these counts are generated is still fairly limited but it seems like this shouldn't be possible?

Here's an example of what I'm seeing.

Before removing libs:

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 68955; max is 65536.

     6 android.accessibilityservice
    15 android.accounts
    23 android.animation
   423 android.app
   222 android.content
    93 android.content.pm
   104 android.content.res
    59 android.database
    24 android.database.sqlite
   228 android.graphics
   111 android.graphics.drawable
     2 android.graphics.drawable.shapes
     3 android.graphics.pdf
    34 android.hardware
     5 android.hardware.display
    11 android.hardware.fingerprint
    26 android.location
   156 android.media
    17 android.media.browse
    87 android.media.session
    66 android.net
     6 android.net.http
     7 android.net.nsd
     2 android.net.wifi
    44 android.opengl
   279 android.os
     7 android.preference
    18 android.print
     5 android.print.pdf
    15 android.provider
     8 android.renderscript
     9 android.security
     6 android.security.keystore
    12 android.speech.tts
    20 android.support.annotation
   124 android.support.customtabs
   320 android.support.graphics.drawable
    19 android.support.graphics.drawable.animated
    19 android.support.v4
    41 android.support.v4.accessibilityservice
    62 android.support.v4.animation
  1632 android.support.v4.app
   272 android.support.v4.content
     1 android.support.v4.content.pm
    20 android.support.v4.content.res
     3 android.support.v4.database
    55 android.support.v4.graphics
   261 android.support.v4.graphics.drawable
    19 android.support.v4.hardware.display
    66 android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint
    74 android.support.v4.internal.view
   645 android.support.v4.media
   818 android.support.v4.media.session
    64 android.support.v4.net
    68 android.support.v4.os
    84 android.support.v4.print
    96 android.support.v4.provider
    14 android.support.v4.speech.tts
   103 android.support.v4.text
   284 android.support.v4.util
  1790 android.support.v4.view
  1116 android.support.v4.view.accessibility
    29 android.support.v4.view.animation
  1402 android.support.v4.widget
   972 android.support.v7.app
    19 android.support.v7.appcompat
    19 android.support.v7.cardview
    69 android.support.v7.graphics.drawable
     1 android.support.v7.recyclerview
     3 android.support.v7.text
     2 android.support.v7.transition
   140 android.support.v7.util
   156 android.support.v7.view
   587 android.support.v7.view.menu
  3899 android.support.v7.widget
   148 android.support.v7.widget.helper
     5 android.support.v7.widget.util
    13 android.telephony
    37 android.text
     3 android.text.method
     2 android.text.style
    17 android.transition
    75 android.util
   706 android.view
   215 android.view.accessibility
    45 android.view.animation
     2 android.view.inputmethod
   171 android.webkit
   694 android.widget
     9 bitter.jnibridge
   257 bolts
     1 com.adcolony.adcolonysdk
  3132 com.adcolony.sdk
   263 com.applovin.adview
   358 com.applovin.impl.adview
   957 com.applovin.impl.sdk
    24 com.applovin.nativeAds
   120 com.applovin.sdk
    73 appnexuscustom.com.playandwin.appnexuscustom
  1148 com.appnexus.opensdk
    32 com.appnexus.opensdk.mediatedviews
    62 com.appnexus.opensdk.transitionanimation
   192 com.appnexus.opensdk.utils
   350 com.appsflyer
    19 com.appsflyer.cache
   441 com.chartboost.sdk
    35 com.chartboost.sdk.InPlay
   183 com.chartboost.sdk.Libraries
    88 com.chartboost.sdk.Model
    68 com.chartboost.sdk.Tracking
  1006 com.chartboost.sdk.impl
   719 com.facebook
    12 com.facebook.ads
    19 com.facebook.android
   214 com.facebook.appevents
    78 com.facebook.appevents.internal
    34 com.facebook.applinks
    13 com.facebook.devicerequests.internal
   763 com.facebook.internal
    27 com.facebook.messenger
   158 com.facebook.unity
    97 com.facebook.share
   624 com.facebook.share.internal
   466 com.facebook.share.model
   392 com.facebook.share.widget
   450 com.facebook.login
   192 com.facebook.login.widget
    31 com.google.ads
   323 com.google.ads.conversiontracking
   109 com.google.ads.mediation
     2 com.google.ads.mediation.admob
    41 com.google.ads.mediation.customevent
   213 com.google.android.gms.ads
    90 com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick
   114 com.google.android.gms.ads.formats
    23 com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier
    18 com.google.android.gms.ads.impl
   543 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal
    67 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.cache
   721 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client
   163 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.formats
   313 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay
    97 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.purchase
   198 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request
   131 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client
    65 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.client
    17 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.safebrowsing
    52 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client
    98 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation
     2 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob
    63 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent
    16 com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase
    22 com.google.android.gms.ads.reward
    14 com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.mediation
   137 com.google.android.gms.ads.search
    18 com.google.android.gms
     4 com.google.android.gms.actions
   381 com.google.android.gms.analytics
    37 com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce
   756 com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal
    79 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin
    20 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal
    18 com.google.android.gms.base
     5 com.google.android.gms.clearcut
   202 com.google.android.gms.common
   258 com.google.android.gms.common.api
   148 com.google.android.gms.common.data
   106 com.google.android.gms.common.images
   632 com.google.android.gms.common.internal
    86 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel
     9 com.google.android.gms.common.server
    42 com.google.android.gms.common.server.converter
   117 com.google.android.gms.common.server.response
    90 com.google.android.gms.common.stats
   122 com.google.android.gms.common.util
   213 com.google.android.gms.dynamic
     1 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
     1 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags
    27 com.google.android.gms.flags.impl
     1 com.google.android.gms.gass.internal
   251 com.google.android.gms.gcm
   134 com.google.android.gms.iid
  6406 com.google.android.gms.internal
   364 com.google.android.gms.location
   402 com.google.android.gms.location.internal
    18 com.google.android.gms.location.places
    34 com.google.android.gms.phenotype
    13 com.google.android.gms.playlog.internal
    13 com.google.android.gms.security
   139 com.google.android.gms.signin.internal
   951 com.google.android.gms.tagmanager
     6 com.google.android.gms.tasks
     4 com.google.firebase
     4 com.google.firebase.iid
     2 com.google.firebase.messaging
   289 com.google.gson
     6 com.google.gson.annotations
   269 com.google.gson.internal
   292 com.google.gson.internal.bind
    18 com.google.gson.reflect
    90 com.google.gson.stream
    24 com.jirbo.adcolony
    46 com.karman.utils
   541 com.leanplum
   536 com.leanplum.a
   209 com.leanplum.a.a
     5 com.leanplum.a.a.a
    91 com.leanplum.activities
    13 com.leanplum.annotations
    29 com.leanplum.callbacks
     7 com.leanplum.json
   121 com.leanplum.messagetemplates
    21 com.leanplum.utils
    26 com.leanplum.views
   366 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy
     1 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy.base.asserts
     1 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy.base.exception
    12 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy.base.functional
    18 com.mopub
   578 com.mopub.common
   225 com.mopub.common.event
     5 com.mopub.common.factories
    24 com.mopub.common.logging
   165 com.mopub.common.util
     6 com.mopub.exceptions
  1409 com.mopub.mobileads
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.adcolony
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.admob
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.base
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.chartboost
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.facebook
    36 com.mopub.mobileads.factories
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.interstitial
    50 com.mopub.mobileads.resource
    35 com.mopub.mobileads.util
     1 com.mopub.mobileads.vungle
   344 com.mopub.mraid
   246 com.mopub.network
    78 com.mopub.unity
   170 com.mopub.volley
   219 com.mopub.volley.toolbox
   273 com.onevcat.uniwebview
    14 com.pch.common
    40 com.pch.leanplumcustommessaging
    30 com.pch.lotto
    18 com.pch.lottoblast
   348 com.prime31
    18 com.prime31.Etcetera
    18 com.prime31.NAME
   891 com.tapjoy
  2572 com.tapjoy.internal
    22 com.tapjoy.mediation
     1 com.tapjoy.mraid
   118 com.tapjoy.mraid.controller
    34 com.tapjoy.mraid.listener
    47 com.tapjoy.mraid.util
   227 com.tapjoy.mraid.view
   245 com.truste.mobile.sdk
    36 com.truste.mobile.sdk.exception
     8 com.truste.unity
   503 com.unity3d.player
    18 com.vungle.log
  6176 com.vungle.publisher
    34 com.vungle.publisher.env
    11 com.vungle.publisher.inject
    41 com.vungle.sdk
    14 dagger
    70 dagger.internal
     4 dagger.multibindings
     2 dalvik.system
     6 default
   222 java.io
   460 java.lang
    10 java.lang.ref
    57 java.lang.reflect
    21 java.math
   104 java.net
    45 java.nio
     7 java.nio.channels
     5 java.nio.charset
    40 java.security
     3 java.security.cert
     2 java.security.spec
     3 java.sql
    22 java.text
   441 java.util
   148 java.util.concurrent
    35 java.util.concurrent.atomic
    21 java.util.concurrent.locks
     4 java.util.jar
    12 java.util.logging
    15 java.util.regex
    18 java.util.zip
    16 javax.crypto
     3 javax.crypto.spec
     2 javax.inject
    12 javax.microedition.khronos.egl
     2 javax.net
    33 javax.net.ssl
     1 javax.security.auth.x500
     5 javax.xml.parsers
    16 org.apache.http
     2 org.apache.http.client
    15 org.apache.http.client.methods
     1 org.apache.http.client.utils
     1 org.apache.http.conn
     7 org.apache.http.entity
     5 org.apache.http.impl.client
     1 org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm
     2 org.apache.http.impl.cookie
     9 org.apache.http.message
     2 org.apache.http.params
    19 org.fmod
    72 org.json
    10 org.w3c.dom
     1 org.xml.sax
    19 org.xmlpull.v1
    10 sun.misc
```

After removing the vungle package:

```
trouble writing output: Too many field references: 71569; max is 65536.

     3 android.accounts
    29 android.app
     1 android.content
    50 android.content.pm
    14 android.content.res
     3 android.database
    59 android.graphics
     2 android.graphics.drawable
     6 android.hardware
     1 android.location
     2 android.media
     1 android.media.browse
     4 android.net
    42 android.os
     3 android.print
     6 android.provider
  1879 android.support.customtabs
  1968 android.support.graphics.drawable
  1815 android.support.graphics.drawable.animated
  1815 android.support.v4
    13 android.support.v4.accessibilityservice
    17 android.support.v4.animation
   770 android.support.v4.app
   110 android.support.v4.content
     1 android.support.v4.content.pm
     9 android.support.v4.graphics
    42 android.support.v4.graphics.drawable
     4 android.support.v4.hardware.display
    12 android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint
     9 android.support.v4.internal.view
   337 android.support.v4.media
   272 android.support.v4.media.session
     5 android.support.v4.net
    19 android.support.v4.os
    49 android.support.v4.print
     9 android.support.v4.provider
     5 android.support.v4.speech.tts
    55 android.support.v4.text
    74 android.support.v4.util
   385 android.support.v4.view
   112 android.support.v4.view.accessibility
     8 android.support.v4.view.animation
   495 android.support.v4.widget
   378 android.support.v7.app
  1815 android.support.v7.appcompat
  1815 android.support.v7.cardview
    18 android.support.v7.graphics.drawable
    14 android.support.v7.recyclerview
     1 android.support.v7.text
     2 android.support.v7.transition
    93 android.support.v7.util
    77 android.support.v7.view
   191 android.support.v7.view.menu
  1335 android.support.v7.widget
    86 android.support.v7.widget.helper
     1 android.support.v7.widget.util
     5 android.text
    15 android.util
    30 android.view
     7 android.webkit
    28 android.widget
  1838 appnexuscustom.com.playandwin.appnexuscustom
     2 bitter.jnibridge
   158 bolts
     6 com.adcolony.adcolonysdk
  2166 com.adcolony.sdk
    88 com.applovin.adview
   168 com.applovin.impl.adview
   612 com.applovin.impl.sdk
    81 com.applovin.sdk
  2344 com.appnexus.opensdk
    13 com.appnexus.opensdk.mediatedviews
    44 com.appnexus.opensdk.transitionanimation
   111 com.appnexus.opensdk.utils
   332 com.appsflyer
     7 com.appsflyer.cache
   256 com.chartboost.sdk
    25 com.chartboost.sdk.InPlay
    93 com.chartboost.sdk.Libraries
   146 com.chartboost.sdk.Model
    33 com.chartboost.sdk.Tracking
   591 com.chartboost.sdk.impl
  2216 com.facebook
     5 com.facebook.ads
  1815 com.facebook.android
   169 com.facebook.appevents
    39 com.facebook.appevents.internal
    46 com.facebook.applinks
     9 com.facebook.devicerequests.internal
   563 com.facebook.internal
   183 com.facebook.login
    81 com.facebook.login.widget
    32 com.facebook.messenger
    51 com.facebook.share
   360 com.facebook.share.internal
   113 com.facebook.share.model
   124 com.facebook.share.widget
    53 com.facebook.unity
    25 com.google.ads
   309 com.google.ads.conversiontracking
    22 com.google.ads.mediation
    11 com.google.ads.mediation.customevent
  1809 com.google.android.gms
    20 com.google.android.gms.actions
  1852 com.google.android.gms.ads
    12 com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick
    19 com.google.android.gms.ads.formats
    13 com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier
  1809 com.google.android.gms.ads.impl
   256 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal
    22 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.cache
   222 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client
   100 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.formats
   158 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay
    51 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.purchase
   197 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request
    14 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client
     6 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.client
     6 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.safebrowsing
    17 com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client
    22 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation
     1 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob
    12 com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent
     7 com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase
     1 com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.mediation
    46 com.google.android.gms.ads.search
  1908 com.google.android.gms.analytics
    14 com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce
   237 com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal
    36 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin
     6 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal
  1809 com.google.android.gms.base
     1 com.google.android.gms.clearcut
    98 com.google.android.gms.common
    95 com.google.android.gms.common.api
    41 com.google.android.gms.common.data
    46 com.google.android.gms.common.images
   188 com.google.android.gms.common.internal
     1 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel
     4 com.google.android.gms.common.server
    12 com.google.android.gms.common.server.converter
    33 com.google.android.gms.common.server.response
    63 com.google.android.gms.common.stats
    22 com.google.android.gms.common.util
    27 com.google.android.gms.dynamic
     2 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
     2 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags
    16 com.google.android.gms.flags.impl
  1910 com.google.android.gms.gcm
  1856 com.google.android.gms.iid
  3552 com.google.android.gms.internal
  1956 com.google.android.gms.location
   100 com.google.android.gms.location.internal
     5 com.google.android.gms.location.places
    18 com.google.android.gms.phenotype
    11 com.google.android.gms.playlog.internal
     6 com.google.android.gms.security
    26 com.google.android.gms.signin.internal
   401 com.google.android.gms.tagmanager
    68 com.google.gson
   115 com.google.gson.internal
   117 com.google.gson.internal.bind
     3 com.google.gson.reflect
    74 com.google.gson.stream
  1821 com.karman.utils
   188 com.leanplum
   242 com.leanplum.a
    87 com.leanplum.a.a
     4 com.leanplum.a.a.a
    13 com.leanplum.activities
     8 com.leanplum.annotations
     5 com.leanplum.callbacks
    40 com.leanplum.messagetemplates
    21 com.leanplum.utils
    13 com.leanplum.views
   175 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy
     2 com.moat.analytics.mobile.tjy.base.functional
  1809 com.mopub
   322 com.mopub.common
   142 com.mopub.common.event
     1 com.mopub.common.factories
     5 com.mopub.common.logging
   112 com.mopub.common.util
   632 com.mopub.mobileads
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.adcolony
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.admob
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.base
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.chartboost
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.facebook
     7 com.mopub.mobileads.factories
     6 com.mopub.mobileads.interstitial
    84 com.mopub.mobileads.resource
   132 com.mopub.mraid
   120 com.mopub.network
    40 com.mopub.unity
   106 com.mopub.volley
    93 com.mopub.volley.toolbox
   118 com.onevcat.uniwebview
     1 com.pch.common
  1820 com.pch.leanplumcustommessaging
  1816 com.pch.lotto
  1809 com.pch.lottoblast
   232 com.prime31
  1809 com.prime31.Etcetera
  1809 com.prime31.NAME
   721 com.tapjoy
  1141 com.tapjoy.internal
    11 com.tapjoy.mediation
     6 com.tapjoy.mraid
    79 com.tapjoy.mraid.controller
    19 com.tapjoy.mraid.listener
    29 com.tapjoy.mraid.util
    84 com.tapjoy.mraid.view
   145 com.truste.mobile.sdk
    17 com.truste.mobile.sdk.exception
     2 com.truste.unity
   235 com.unity3d.player
     2 java.io
    28 java.lang
    11 java.lang.annotation
     1 java.math
     2 java.nio
     6 java.util
     6 java.util.concurrent
     8 java.util.logging
     4 javax.microedition.khronos.egl
    20 org.fmod
     1 org.json
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582850/unity-too-many-field-references-70613-max-is-65536/42583210#42583210) for this without removing some libs.

Comment: As to why count increases when libs are removed, I think you should update your question with the official ref count. Post the lib names remove followed by ref count after that. This will help people figure out your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll add some more info to the question. 

The Android Studio project solution is still something I'm thinking about. I did try it, but the resulting project wouldn't build. I attempted to get that project working but it was well over my head, I haven't done much with AS. I didn't want to get into multi-dex anyhow, but maybe proguard would be enough to solve my problem.