# Android back button, exit the project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I use Gradle to export `unity project` into Android Studio.

*When I run project in phone, when I press back button, project exits immediately*, but I write code to pause the game when I press back button. When I open the project again, game is in pause mode.

**I don't want to exit project with back button.**

It works correctly when I build project with unity, but because of 64K error, I need to export it.
Any idea?

Comment: You don't have to export the project when you have that error. Read from **FIX WITHOUT EXPORTING THE PROJECT** in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42583210/3785314). You must have Unity 5.5 and above to do the non export solution

Comment: yeah, i use gradle inside unity too, but again, when i use back button, it minimized my game again and do what i write in code too...

Comment: I suspect that one of your plugins is doing this.

Comment: i mean, when i use Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape), this thing happens, because its not do anything in splash screen because i don't have this function there.

Answer (score 0):

In android, you can @Override below method on Main Activity to exit from the application. Here you can also show any popup/toast

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //super.onBackPressed(); Enable if you want to exit from application
}
```

Comment: if i insert this code into my Activity, what happens to my unity scripts that i write before? they override to this function too?

Comment: You can try once. I guess.

Comment: public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity, i added code into this class, but not works, again minimized application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Activity and then you can also add your own code in this method also.

With the following code, your activity back button has stopped working.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Comment: if i insert this code into my Activity, what happens to my unity scripts that i write before? they override to this function too?

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty game object in your Unity3D scene and add this script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class backButtonAndroid : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

follow the instructions here if you do not know how to export the project to Android : https://medium.com/@angelhiadefiesta/integrate-a-unity-module-to-a-native-android-app-87644fe899e0

then go to YOUR APP in Android Studio and put `android:process=":UnityKillsMe"` in your unity activity. It should look like this:

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.yourpackageinfo.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:process=":UnityKillsMe">
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
```

Ensure that `android:launchMode="singleTask"` is there too.

Tested on Android 8.1 with Unity 2018.1 on Nexus 5x device including also Vuforia libraries for Unity.

hf