# How to solve too many field references: 79266; max is 65536

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My Project uses these plugins:

- GooglePlayServices
- Google AdMob
- Facebook SDK
- Unity IAP
- FireBase

I have tried this solution. Link:
[Too many field references: 70613; max is 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582850/too-many-field-references-70613-max-is-65536)

And I am facing this problem while importing to android studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLagN.png)

Comment: Sorry, do not just say it's not working. Explain what you mean by that. It should if you follow that instruction. There are two solutions there. One that requires you build it and one that you can o from the Editor. Try both of them. If not working, tell us what you mean by that. If possible, show the steps you did in your own question and I will point out what you missed.

Comment: I am getting this error on Unity 3d as well on android after importing project.
[Image] https://imgur.com/a/yqU3W

Comment: Create a new question with that error since it's a different error. Don't ask a question with different error that has nothing to do with your real error. Meanwhile I do suggest you delete all your plugins then install them again.

Comment: Let me try this and thank you so much.