# Unity: Gradle build failed Plugins: Unity IAP 1.16 Facebook SDK 7.13.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

using `Gradle` build type and get this error. I want to know how i can fix it. I want to know the way how to find this duplicate class definitions. [Have use this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582850/too-many-field-references-70613-max-is-65536) but still have same problem. There are installed plagins: Unity IAP 1.16, Facebook SDK 7.13.0, Google Play Service 0.9.50, Appodeal 2.8.45. Unity 2017.1.2p3. jdk1.8.0_181 and latest version of sdk tools. Is at correct to use

```
-dontwarn com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdEventListener
```

or no?

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: there were 12 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.af: can't find superclass or interface com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.d: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.l: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.m$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.n: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdBannerListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.u: can't find superclass or interface com.my.target.ads.MyTargetView$MyTargetViewListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.am: can't find superclass or interface com.yandex.mobile.ads.InterstitialEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.b: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.d: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdDisplayListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.m: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.m: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.n$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.o: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdInterstitialListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.t: can't find superclass or interface com.ironsource.mediationsdk.sdk.InterstitialListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.b.x: can't find superclass or interface com.my.target.ads.InterstitialAd$InterstitialAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.b: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.d: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.h: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.k: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.c.w: can't find superclass or interface com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.af$1: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJConnectListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.ag: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJPlacementListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.ag: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJPlacementVideoListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.ai: can't find superclass or interface com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.an$1: can't find superclass or interface com.vungle.publisher.VungleInitListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.ao: can't find superclass or interface com.vungle.publisher.VungleAdEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.d: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.f: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.f: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdDisplayListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.f: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.f: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdRewardListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.f: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdVideoPlaybackListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.j: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.RewardedVideoAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.k$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.l: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdInterstitialListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.p: can't find superclass or interface com.ironsource.mediationsdk.sdk.RewardedVideoListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.e.v: can't find superclass or interface com.my.target.ads.InterstitialAd$InterstitialAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.ac$1: can't find superclass or interface com.vungle.publisher.VungleInitListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.ad: can't find superclass or interface com.vungle.publisher.VungleAdEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.d: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.d: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdDisplayListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.d: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.d: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdRewardListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.d: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdVideoPlaybackListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.g$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.h: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdInterstitialListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.p: can't find superclass or interface com.my.target.ads.InterstitialAd$InterstitialAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.u$1: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJConnectListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.v: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJPlacementListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.v: can't find superclass or interface com.tapjoy.TJPlacementVideoListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.g.x: can't find superclass or interface com.unity3d.ads2.IUnityAdsListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.c$1: can't find superclass or interface com.appnext.appnextsdk.API.AppnextAPI$AppnextAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.c$b: can't find superclass or interface com.appnext.appnextsdk.API.Native
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.e$1: can't find superclass or interface com.avocarrot.androidsdk.AvocarrotCustomListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.g$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.h$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.h$a: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.k$1: can't find superclass or interface com.my.target.nativeads.NativeAd$NativeAdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.networks.h: can't find superclass or interface com.chartboost.sdk.ChartboostDelegate
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwall.TabListFragment$16: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.MediaViewListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwall.TabListFragment$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwall.TabListFragment$3: can't find superclass or interface ru.mail.android.mytarget.nativeads.NativePromoAd$NativePromoAdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwall.TabListFragment$d$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.NativeAdScrollView$AdViewProvider
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwall.view.MVNativeAdScrollView: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.NativeAdScrollView
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwallex.a$3: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwallex.a$4: can't find superclass or interface ru.mail.android.mytarget.nativeads.NativePromoAd$NativePromoAdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.appwallex.a$d$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.NativeAdScrollView$AdViewProvider
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.AdmobAdapter$1: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAppInstallAd$OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.AdmobAdapter$2: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeContentAd$OnContentAdLoadedListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.AdmobAdapter$3: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAppInstallAd$OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.AdmobAdapter$4: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeContentAd$OnContentAdLoadedListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.AdmobAdapter$5: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.FacebookAdapter$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.FacebookAdapter$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.NativeAdsManager$Listener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.base.adapter.MyTargetAdapter$MyTagerPromadListener: can't find superclass or interface ru.mail.android.mytarget.nativeads.NativePromoAd$NativePromoAdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.mvnative.controller.NativeController$5: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.mvnative.controller.NativeController$8: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.nativex.view.MVMediaView$9: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.ads.MediaViewListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.b$1: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdRewardListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.b$2: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdVideoPlaybackListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.b$3: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdDisplayListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.b$4: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdClickListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.b$5: can't find superclass or interface com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinAdLoadListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.d: can't find superclass or interface com.nativex.monetization.listeners.OnAdEventV2
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.d: can't find superclass or interface com.nativex.monetization.listeners.SessionListener
Warning: com.mobvista.msdk.reward.a.d$1: can't find superclass or interface com.nativex.monetization.listeners.RewardListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.a: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequest
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.MobileAds
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequest
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.MobileAds
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.ae: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.af: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdEventListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.af: can't find referenced class com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdRequestError
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.b: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads.a.c: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
Warning: com.appodeal.ads<message truncated>
```

Comment: Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: `Note: there were 12 duplicate class definitions.` that is the key. Sometimes different libraries will import other libraries in order to work, and in some cases, you will have the same dependency-library but with a different version. A silly example; a library will import `com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0` and another will import `com.android.support.appcompat-v7-25.2.0`.
Now, you will have to search for duplicated libraries in your project, and that can take some time...

Answer (score 0):

just use -dontwarn in proguard.pro like below

-dontwarn com.applovin.sdk.**