# Generate signed bundle/APK doesn't include the plugins

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

My Unity project uses several plugins so I can't build APK file, too many field references: mine is over 96000; max is 65536. 
I google and know the android studio build, I followed all the steps and build completed.
The problem is when I build APK file for debug, everything works perfectly fine. But when I generate signed apk which is complete with no error, I install the apk file and I realize that all my plugins don't work, not a single one. Can anyone help me with this problem?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: which SDK are you using?

Comment: Facebook SDK
GoogleMobileAds
GooglePlayGamesPlugin

Comment: and what about android SDK?

Comment: What do you mean adroid SDK?

Comment: You should enable Multidex: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582850/too-many-field-references-70613-max-is-65536

Comment: I already tried it many times as i mentioned on the topic but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate, but this is a limitation of android when you publish a game. If you use to many plugin and you overlap the field reference you can't publish it.

Try to delete all unused plugin first. After if you use only small part of each plugin try find a plugin that fit your more your need.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm was trying to do that.