# Open Unity games from an Android Studio app

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an Android Studio application that doesn't have anything to do with games, but as a feature I want to add games that people can play for fun. So in my application I've added a menu with two button that I want to use to select the games. I've made two games with Unity that I exported as Android with Gradle build. The games work fine when I import them separately as new projects.

But I can't seem to figure out how to make one Android Studio application that has a menu to play the games. The games also need a button or something to go back to the menu, which seems even more difficult.

I really have no idea how to even begin working on this, I'm hoping that someone here has some experience to point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance,
Frenk

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918417/display-unity-scene-as-sub-view-in-android-studio)?

Comment: thanks for the link @Programmer I'll give it a try