# Porting Android SurfaceView Game to Unity Engine on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, surfaceview

I have a published 2D puzzle game (require drawing 400 small images in each frame) on Android developed using SurfaceView. Due to performance issues on some tablets and phones, I am forced to look at other alternatives. It looks like Unity is the best option. Before I do this, I have several questions.

1. Can unity provide faster and consistent performance on most of Android devices? (like drawing 400 items every frame)
2. Can I mix Android Layouts and activities with Unity
   Activity. (What I mean here is can I just replace the game play part
   with unity keeping the existing implementation of the game using
   android layouts/fragments/activities)
3. Can I call google play in-app purchases from Unity
   Game canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**.If the images are very small then it might be able to. Use the the [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) or [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) component to display each image. If performance is still bad, you can use *GPU instancing* which has been made more easier to use in Unity lately.

**2**.You can write a Java plugin and load it from Unity or you can even write your Activity in Java with layouts and then control your Unity program from it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918417/display-unity-scene-as-sub-view-in-android-studio/43921522#43921522) post for more information on that.

Even though it is possible, *don't do it*. Only write a Java code when you have to otherwise, you will end up with a game that works on Android only. The point of using Unity is to make a Game that works on most devices. Port all your code to C#. That's what I would do.

**3**.Yes, you can use google play in-app purchases in Unity with the Prime31 plugin or you can use Unity IAP that's easy to use and requires no plugin at-all.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer. Before I do anything just want to focus more on Question 1. I am trying to port to Unity because of performance issues of android canvas. If performance is bad no point porting. My game is a Jigsaw puzzle, where a image is downloaded and then broken into say 400 paces. So do you reckon this can be handled better in Unity becuase I only load 1 image.

Comment: Give it a try. Just try to display 400 tiny images and see if you are fine with the framerate. If not use GPU instancing  like I mentioned. You can instantiate thousands of objects with GPU instancing. One down side of GPU instancing is that the mobile device must be running OpenGL-ES 3 and above. So, GPU instancing  will not work on older devices running with OpenGL-ES 2.