# Access Unity 3d UI component like Panel/Image as a view in Objective C code

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a certain task where i want to pass a UIView to one of the SDK's in my iOS project.
Now, my project is a simple 2D game build in Unity 3d. I want to send the Panel in my Canvas to that SDK as UIView.

I am aware of iOS and Unity communication. It happens using as Char*.

I am not sure how should i access that GameObject Panel in my iOS code as UIView. I will be very thankful if i receive any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Above is one of solution that you can access from ios interface but before see this, read https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html. it will help to understand how unity and native code can communicate.

iOS: test.mm

```
#import "Unity/UnityInterface.h"

...
...

-(void)SendMessage
{
    UnitySendMessage("MessageGameCommunicator", "Receiver", [message UTF8String]);
}
```

Unity: Commnicator.cs, MessageGameCommunicator (GameObject name)

```
    public class Commnicator : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static void Receiver(string message)
        {
            // ...
            // Do something.
        }
    }
```

After Unity interface get message from ios, you can implement whatever you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619463/android-changing-unity-scene-from-ui-components-outside-the-scene

it looks same purpose but link is for Android.