# Apk extraction from unity using android studio

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have exported a project from Unity to Android Studio. In Android Studio, I am not able to generate APK. Generate APK option is not available in Android Studio. I have attached the image of build options below.

[image]

Comment: Go to Build ---> Build APK(s) as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Nothing is happening on clicking that Build APKS(S) button.Not even any tasks are running in android studio.

Comment: Should i add any extra files ?

Comment: Clean, Rebuild Project then try the Build APK again

Comment: Tried it , Cleaned project and rebuild project and clciked build apk , But its not working

Comment: Even the Event Log Window is not changing? I suggest you restart Android Studio. If that doesn't work, delete the project, re-export it from Unity and re-import into Android Studio. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980792/exporting-and-running-unity3d-project-to-android-studio/39008549?s=1|73.1826#39008549) tutorial for more info

Comment: Ok, will check it

Comment: I have checked it by re importing the project again .But its working like old project only , Build APK is not working , I am using android studio 3.0.1 version.
I have checked the sample project from here"https://github.com/inbgche/Unity-Android-Communication". Facing same problem  :(