# No AndroidManifest.xml on my Unity project

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I wan't to create a mobile game for Android and iOS and I wan't to allow this game only on mobile devices (no tablets, TV, watches ...).

I work with Unity and for iOS I just found the button "Target Device : iPhone Only".

My problem is for Android devices ... There is no button like for iOS.

After a few researches, I just found that I have to add some lines on the AndroidManifest.xml file. But There is no AndroidManifest.xml file on my project and it's impossible to create a new xml file with Unity.

Need your help guys ...

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building apk you can export your game as android project - and then change your manifest as you wish.
[image]

Here is nice explanation how to export
[Exporting and running Unity3D project to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980792/exporting-and-running-unity3d-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: Hey ! I work on Mac and I don't have this option but I'll try this on my Windows. Thanks for your answer, I'll keep you posted.