# when every i try to upload app in google console its show this error

Tags: android, console, unity-game-engine

my game made in Unity. and when ever i try to upload game apk it shows this error.

Unoptimized APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

Comment: Use Android app bundle instead of generating APK. In Android Studio go to **Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/ APK**

Comment: It is not error it is just warning , you can continue to publish your game

Comment: @phantasm when it show the error not allowing to publish,  publish button disabled . check my below image i share it

Comment: @rahulkhurana the game create in unity then how can i export it to android studio

Comment: @AsifJalil this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39008549/4079010)

Comment: Have you complete Store Listing,Price & Distribution,Content Rating and App Content in Play Console?

Comment: @phantasm yes i done every thing but at last time when click review then i received this error and cant published my game

Comment: @phantasm when i build apk from unity its working fine and run, but when i try to upload it then google console says make apk with android build bundle, but the issue is when i export my project with the support of gradle then gradle show update your version and not making any apk so confuse, search all internet but not finding any solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations
[image]

Comment: yes i am doing the same but still its not uploading check my screenshot

Comment: You say you uploaded an APK, but the output file (after a build in Unity) is supposed to be .aab?!